# Is it possible to get notified just before an object is about to get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### The Question

With `FinalizationRegistry`, it's possible to get notified after that an object has been garbage collected. However, is it possible to get notified before, so I can still have access to the data and do something with it?

### What I'm trying to achieve

I want to implement a `CompressedMap<K, V>` were data is internally stored, either deflated in a `Map<K, Buffer>` or inflated in a `Map<K, WeakRef<V>>`. It's up to the user to define the `deflate` and `inflate` functions.

As a classic `Map<K, V>`, if the user holds a reference to a value present in the map, and update it, it should also be automatically updated in the map (because it's the same object). That's why I need to keep the values in a `Map<K, WeakRef<V>>` and compress and move them to the `Map<K, Buffer>` only when they're about to get garbage collected.

### What I've already considered

#### SO question: [Can I get a callback when my object is about to get collected by GC in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67569885/can-i-get-a-callback-when-my-object-is-about-to-get-collected-by-gc-in-node)

The accepted answer shows how to use `FinalizationRegistry` which fires a callback AFTER that the object has been garbage collected and is no longer available.

#### Moving the value to the deflated map after each modification

It would require to wrap each fields of the object in a getter/setter and it has lot of implications:

1. It's more computational intensive to update the deflated map after EACH modification.
2. Modifications on new fields (not wrapped in getter/setter) would be ignored.
3. Wrapping each fields of each objects could have a big memory impact on large map which would defeat the purpose of a "compressed map".
4. It would modify the user's objects.
5. It questions where the boundary of the object is. Maybe we should wrap all the fields even deep ones, maybe not. It depends of the user's use case.

#### Writing a Node.JS addon and using Node-API

I didn't dig deeply into it, but it would be a last resort solution, because my implementation will only be compatible with Node.JS. Even if I'm focused on Node.JS, browser support would be nice to have. Also I never wrote a Node.JS addon, and I'm not even sure if it will allow me to implement a `PreFinalizationRegistry`.

### References

- [FinalizationRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [WeakRef](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef)

Comment: I already though of something similar, but it has a lot of drawbacks. See "Moving the value to the deflated map after each modification". It's not exactly your proposition, but there is some drawbacks in common

Comment: If you want to implement a proxy on an arbitrary object, you have to wrap every properties in getters/setters which would cause the drawbacks 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Since the keys of a WeakMap are objects, a WeakMap entry can only be garbage-collected if there is no reference to its key any more. Even if you could be given a chance to compress the about-to-be-collected value, under which key would you store the compressed value in the Map?

Comment: @heiko-theißen I misunderstood how WeakMap are working. I thought that a WeakMap held weak references to its values, not keys. That's explains why keys need to be objects.

Comment: So in my example, instead of using a WeakMap<K, V>, I could use a Map<K, WeakRef<T>>.

Comment: @Keith OK I see, the user is required to call the getter each time they want to access/modify the wrapped object. But what happen if the user use the getter hold a reference to the wrapped object, and then modify the wrapped object again, without calling the getter? That will break things right? I wanted to implement a CompressedMap that is fully transparent to the user and doesn't need additional thought to use than a traditional Map.

Comment: Imagine an unreferenced object `{a: 1, b: {c: 2}}` for which there is still a reference to its `b` subobject. If the object was compressed and then garbage-collected, the holder of the reference to `b` might say `ref_to_b.c = 3`, and this change would not automatically be reflected in the compressed version. So when the compressed version is later re-inflated, it still has `b.c = 2`.

How would the envisaged "compressed map" deal with such cases?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen This is something that I overlooked. I think that the only way to handle that is to have generic deflate/inflate functions (not user defined ones), because a user defined deflate<A> can't handle inputs with A['b'] types (TS notation). Given that it's possible to be notified before garbage collection, the deflate function would register WeakRefs on the fields of the object that are themselves objects, and these sub-objects would be deflated on cleanup as well. The inflate function would reconstruct the object and re-attach the references.

Comment: You mean that every sub-object must be replaced by a weak reference before deflation? But would work only if the subjects are also in the compressed map.

Comment: No, I mean that the CompressedMap should register (internally) WeakRefs to the sub-objects during deflation. The the sub-objects would then be deflated when they are themselves reclaimed. The case were the object and the sub-objects are reclaimed at the same time should be taken into account, but that shouldn't be the hard part. Anyway, this complicates a lot the implementation of the CompressedMap.

Comment: So you deflate one object, but at the same time insert many inflated sub-objects. How big is the benefit of such a partial deflation?

Comment: I don't create new inflated sub-objects, just weak references to already existing ones. The inflated sub-objects that the references points to would most-likely be quickly reclaimed anyway. About the benefit, it will depend of the use case. The only way to know is to test an implementation.

Comment: @Keith I thought that you were talking about implementing a proxy design pattern. I didn't knew about the Proxy object in JS. I think that it's indeed a good idea. However, how would you change the user's reference to the object on a Map.set? You can wrap the parameter, but can't change the actual reference or any other references that the user may have.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to track lifetime's of objects.  Unless the object is something you created,..  And then you can create a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

> Developers shouldn't rely on cleanup callbacks for essential program logic. Cleanup callbacks may be useful for reducing memory usage across the course of a program, but are unlikely to be useful otherwise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry#notes_on_cleanup_callbacks

Instead of waiting until the object is finalized, I would recommend using `setTimeout()` to deflate it when it hasn't been used for a certain period of time.

To do so you'll want to return an object that behaves like a `Map<K, WeakRef<V>>` and wraps it instead of the actual map. This way you can start throwing exceptions if it is used after the timeout.

Comment: An object is "used" as long as there is a reference to it. Knowing whether that is the case is the job of the garbage collector, how can the "compressed map" know this?

Comment: "Cleanup callbacks may be useful for reducing memory usage" this is exactly what my use-case is. Also, I can't deflate an object if the user still holds a reference to it, because if they modify it, the modification will be lost. "You can start throwing exceptions if it is used after the timeout." That's not a possibility, who want to use a Map that throws an exception is you use a value after an arbitrary amount of time? The timeout here is the lifetime of the object, which could be from 0 to infinity depending of the object. There is not a global value that all stored objects should follow.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an unreferenced object `{a: 1, b: {c: 2}}` for which there is still a reference to its `b` subobject. If the object was compressed and then garbage-collected, the holder of the reference to `b` might say `ref_to_b.c = 3`, and this change would not automatically be reflected in the compressed version. So when the compressed version is later re-inflated, it still has `b.c = 2`.

This means that you can only compress those members of an object that are not themselves objects, that is, the primitive-valued members. And this could be done with a setter whenever such a value is changed. The deflated values would be kept with strong references, so that an object can always be recreated from them if only its key is known, even if its earlier incarnation has been garbage-collected.

```js
class DeflatableObject {
  static deflated = {
    primitive: new Map(),
    subobject: new Map()
  }
  static recreate(key) {
    var obj = new DeflatableObject();
    obj.key = key;
    obj._primitive = inflate(DeflatableObject.deflated.primitive.get(key));
    var subobj = DeflatableObject.deflated.subobject.get(key);
    if (subobj)
      obj._subobject = subobj.object.deref() || DeflatableSubobject.recreate(subobj.key);
    return obj;
  }
  set primitive(value) {
    this._primitive = value;
    DeflatableObject.deflated.primitive.set(this.key, deflate(value));
  }
  get primitive() {
    return this._primitive;
  }
  set subobject(value) {
    this._subobject = value;
    DeflatableObject.deflated.subobject.set(this.key, {
      object: new WeakRef(value),
      key: value.key
    });
  }
  get subobject() {
    return this._subobject;
  }
}
```